# AndroidJUnitRunner and JUnit versions after 4.10

Tags: android, android-testing, android-junit, androidjunitrunner

According to [`AndroidJUnitRunner` documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/junit-runner.html),

> The test runner is compatible with your JUnit 3 and JUnit 4 (up to JUnit 4.10) tests

Does it mean there are known incompatibilities with 4.11 and 4.12, and if so, what are they? Or was this simply written long ago and not revised? Or some other option?

I did try to search for it, but couldn't find any documents to second the statement or any practical experience shared by another user.